# What is the best practice for version control when using supabase locally with a Flutter project?

Tags: flutter, supabase

I am starting a new Flutter project and using Supabase as it's backend.

I can initialize Supabase within the Flutter project folder, or I can create a separate folder and initialize it there.

With a requirement to keep the application code and the database schema in sync, while also factoring in the long term effects of either file and folder organization, which would be the best practice?

In other words, is it the best practice to have Flutter application code and Supabase database logic in one repository; or is it to have the application code and database layer separated into two repositories?

*NOTE: I come from the RoR world, so having the database and app code in the same folder seems normal, but I wonder if it's better to keep them separate.*

Comment: Whether you want to keep them in the same folder or not is completely up to your preference.

Comment: @dshukertjr thanks for the input. So I guess there is no best practice?

Comment: No, feel free to do whatever you feel is most comfortable for you.